# Create backup tables periodically

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to take a backup of two of my tables in Oracle Database. The backup should happen on each 15 days i.e. on 1st and 15th of each month.
Is there any way to automate this in Oracle through a procedure ?

Currently I do it may manually running a `create table xxx_DDMM as select * from xxx;`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can schedule periodic jobs with Oracle Scheduler. Sample example:

```
--Create job.
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
    job_name           =>  'BACKUP_TABLE',
    job_type           =>  'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action         =>
    q'[
      begin
        execute immediate 'create table xxx_'||to_char(sysdate, 'DDMM')||' as select * from xxx';
      end;
    ]',
    repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=DAILY;BYMONTHDAY=1,15;BYHOUR=8;BYMINUTE=0;',
    enabled            =>  true);
END;
/

--Test and monitor job:
begin
    dbms_scheduler.run_job('BACKUP_TABLE');
end;
/

select * from dba_scheduler_jobs where job_name = 'BACKUP_TABLE';
select * from dba_scheduler_job_run_details where job_name = 'BACKUP_TABLE' order by log_date;
```